# avoid crashing when sending message to non-existent process

Tags: erlang

In the code below, if `!` call fails then my program crashes. I would like to return, say, `{no_process, "some_process"}` instead of crashing. How to achieve this? (I know it is a trivial question for an experienced Erlang developer, which I am not yet...)

```
test() ->
    some_process ! {test},
    ok.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this error happens only if you use atom instead of a process identifier. So you can try to find pid of the desired process using `erlang:whereis/1` and if you get `undefined` you know that name is not registered and you can return you `{no_process, ProcessName}`, otherwise send the message to the `Pid` you got. Something like this:

```
send_msg(Name, Msg) when is_atom(Name) ->
   case erlang:whereis(Name) of
      undefined -> {no_process, Name};
      Pid -> Pid ! Msg
   end;
send_msg(PidOrTuple, Msg) ->
   PidOrTuple ! Msg.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just trap an exception which occurs when you are sending a message to a process which doesn't exists. This is an example of function doing that:

```
send_msg(Process, Msg) ->
    try
        Process ! Msg,
        ok
    catch
        error:badarg -> {no_process, Process}
    end.
```

To send your message just call:

```
send_msg(some_process, Msg).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use pid rather than registered name, it won't fail.

Generally the registered process are monitored in a supervision tree, and each supervisor is in charge of the start and restart policy of its children. For short living process, it is better to avoid name registration.